# Lock Cells Less Than Zero and Empty Cells VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, locking, cells

So basically I want to be able to lock B2:B7 when B1 <0 , when B2:B7 = 0 and when B2:B7 are blank.

This is what I have so far.

SN: I just started this so I am a bit clueless on somethings.

```
Sub test_lock()

If Range("B1") < 0 And Range("B2:B7") Then
    Range("B2:B7").Locked = True

ElseIf Range("B2:B7") > 0 Then
    Range("B2:B7").Locked = False

End If

For Each rngTemp In Range("B2:B7").Cells
        With rngTemp
            If .Value > 0 Or Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                .Locked = False
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.  It locks the whole range and then just unlocks whats needed.

By building the range up and then unlocking all at once it should work faster if the number of cells is high.

Note the commented out line, this just would colour the unlocked cells green for easier checking.

```
Sub temp()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim inRng As Range
Dim rRng As Range

set myRng = Range("A1:B2")

myRng.Locked = True
For Each rCell In myRng
    If rCell.Value > 0 Then
        If rRng Is Nothing Then
            Set rRng = rCell
        Else
            Set rRng = Application.Union(rRng, rCell)
        End If
        End If
    Next
    rRng.Locked = False
    'rRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I think it's working but there is a little problem. Its giving me Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set and when I debug it highlights rRng.Locked = False

Comment: Is there any cells that need to be unlocked.  Might cause an error if rRng is empty.  Also i noticed my initial range is different then yours did you change that back.